# Predicate push down is not working in spark/hive view table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, parquet, amazon-emr

From my reading, spark predict push down will be used in source side(reduced data scan).

- EMR 5.32.x
- Spark version - 2.4.5
- Hive version - 2.x
- data volume 2+ Terabytes.

I have hive/spark table which is created by another function team. They have also created view on top on this table.
The only difference between source table and view is **create_date** column data type

- **base table -> create_date -> date**
- **view -> create_date -> timestamp**

Issue:
Predicate push down applied only on base table query and not in view query.

Base table Query:

```
spark.sql("""select company_id, create_date 
from `db`.`table` where product_name = 'sm' and
create_date = cast('2018-07-01' as date) and country ='selva'""").explain(True)
```

Physical plan

> == Physical Plan ==
> *(1) Project [company_id#1993L, create_date#1997]
> +- *(1) Filter (((isnotnull(create_date#1997) && isnotnull(country#2003)) && (create_date#1997 = 17713)) &&
> (country#2003 = selva))    +- *(1) FileScan parquet
> db.table[company_id#1993L,create_date#1997,country#2003,product_name#2080]
> Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location:
> PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[s3://location...,
> PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(product_name#2080), (product_name#2080 =
> sm)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(create_date),
> IsNotNull(country), **EqualTo(create_date,2018-07-01)**, Equ...,
> ReadSchema:
> struct<company_id:bigint,create_date:date,country:string>

View Query:

```
spark.sql(
        """
    select 
    create_date
    from db.view where 
    product_name = 'sm' and country ='United States'
    """
    ).filter("cast(create_date as date) = cast('2018-07-01' as date)").explain(True)
```

> == Physical Plan ==
> *(1) Project [cast(create_date#2176 as timestamp) AS create_date#2087]
> +- *(1) Filter (((isnotnull(country#2182) && isnotnull(create_date#2176)) && (country#2182 = United
> States)) && (cast(cast(create_date#2176 as timestamp) as date)
> = 17713))    +- *(1) FileScan parquet db.table[create_date#2176,country#2182,product_name#2259]
> Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location:
> PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[s3://location...,
> PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(product_name#2259), (product_name#2259 =
> sm)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(country),
> IsNotNull(create_date), EqualTo(country,United States)],
> ReadSchema: struct<create_date:date,country:string>

OR

```
spark.sql(
        """
    select 
    create_date
    from db.table where 
    product_name = 'sm' and country ='United States'
    """
    ).filter("create_date = cast('2018-07-01' as timestamp)").explain(True)
```

Physical plan:

> == Physical Plan ==
> *(1) Project [cast(create_date#2354 as timestamp) AS create_date#2265]
> +- *(1) Filter (((isnotnull(create_date#2354) && isnotnull(country#2360)) && (country#2360 = United States)) &&
> (cast(create_date#2354 as timestamp) = 1530403200000000))
> +- *(1) FileScan parquet db.table[create_date#2354,country#2360,product_name#2437]
> Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location:
> PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[s3:location..,
> PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(product_name#2437), (product_name#2437 =
> sm)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(create_date),
> IsNotNull(country), EqualTo(country,United States)], ReadSchema:
> struct<create_date:date,country:string>

Comment: in the table query you are using condition in the sql query where clause but for the view query you are using filter on the dataframe which reads the query. Can you eliminate the filter clause and add that to the where clause in the sql query and check.

Comment: I tried both within sql and filter clause but the physical plan is same.